# How can I prove my ISP that my new connection is not stable

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

So I recently involuntary got a new ISP. I have the following problem

- Many times page loading bar will get about 10%, stop there and nothing happens. The page itself is blank (In Safari) In Firefox it just shows on bottom status bar "Looking for google.com..." After a while this problem goes away itself until appears again at some random point.

I tried running speedtest.net, but it returns good results. Trying a server 2000km away, it returns - 10mb down, 9mb up and 100ms ping. So I guess I cannot complain about that.

I have tried both different wireless routers and both different OS (OSX and Windows)

Are there any other tools that I could use to prove that at some points my network just gets completely unusable?

Comment: This sounds like a DNS resolution issue, rather than a bandwidth problem (which your successful bandwidth tests support). have you confirmed that your DNS server addresses are correctly set for your new provider, or tried using alternate DNS servers? look at this utility for testing DNS latency: https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm

Comment: Or this one, https://code.google.com/p/namebench/downloads/list by Google.

Comment: I am using ISP configured router, so I suppose that yes. Problem also persisted when I changed them to 8.8.8.8. (google servers)

Comment: Here I am using IP address, I used to get around 30 ping with old ISP: http://i.imgur.com/l62RCRT.png Would this screenshot be sufficient to show for ISP, that network is not stable? Or such deviations can be norm?

Comment: many ISP-provided modem/router combos have a log and status page. Arris modems might be 192.168.100.1 (even if your assigned ip is on a different subnet) which you can check via a browser page. The logfile will show modem reboots. Check the equipment model and/or post the equipment and provider if you cannot find the info.

Comment: You need to simplify your setup by connecting your PC directly to the router with an Ethernet cable.  With wireless in the picture, the ISP will always have an excuse to blame your side of the network (which it has no control of).

Answer (score 0):

See [dslreports.com/speedtest](http://dslreports.com/speedtest) for a no-Flash-required speed test that also measure bufferbloat.

Also consider running a constant once-per-second ping of both your local home gateway, and your ISP's first-hop router at the far end of your broadband link. Let it run and see if the packet loss for the far router significantly exceeds the packet loss of the nearby router. Even though consumer ISPs don't make service level guarantees, packet loss should be below 1%, and if it's as high as maybe 3%, they really can't shrug it off.